# will a c# function returning an array create a new copy of the array?

Tags: c#

```
class comm
{
public Socket sock;
public byte[] buf;
public int pos;
public comm()
{
buf = new byte[4000];
pos = 0;
}
    public byte[] func(int n)
    {
        byte[] msg;
        msg = new byte[4000];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
         {
            if(pos >= buf.length)
           {
            sock.Receive(buf, 0, 4000, 0);
            pos = 0;
           }
          msg[i] = buf[pos++];
          }
        Array.Resize(ref msg, n);
        return msg;
    }
}
```

I am wondering if this will create a copy of msg?

the idea is to return n bytes of the stream and save the rest for the next call to func.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it returns a copy of the *reference* to array, the memory allocated (on Heap in this case) is not copied by any means.